# Delay Hdmi Output to one of the screens

Tags: debian, ubuntu, video, xrandr, hdmi

I need to delay the output to *one* of my screens, I tried looking for the answers all over the Internet but to no avail. Is this possible, if so how can I do this in terminal?

Update: Both of my displays are mirrored, i want the data to appear slower on the second monitor

Update2: The card I'm running is an amd r9 + amd a8 apu and I'm not really sure of further details right now. I would need to delay the second monitor by around 0.005s or 0.5ms.

Answer (score 2):

We usually want to eliminate display lag. 
You're wanting to undo decades' worth of research...

Anyway, you can achieve this by removing the mirroring, creating a VM, running that in fullscreen on a seperate instance of X which gets the second monitor, then using VNC in fullscreen to show the host's desktop.

Or use OBS* to stream the host to the VM or a second window on the second monitor. This gives you a more arbitrary control over the delay.

*) https://obsproject.com/